# duplicate and clone div

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

sorry i do not speak english well, i want to create a tool that allows to duplicate a div thanks to an "input number" and a button and then I also want to clone this tool by reinitializing it to be able to use the tool again , Here is a piece of code:

```js
$(function() {
 $('#btn_dupliquate').on('click', function() {
   var numDuplication = $('#num-duplication').val();
    
    if (numDuplication > -1) {
     var div = $('.common_preview');
      $('.result').html('');
     for (var i = 0; i < numDuplication; i++) {
       $('.result').append(div.clone());
      }
    }
  });
});




 $(function() {
 $(".heading").keyup(function() {
 var heading=$(this).val();
 $(".common_preview").html("<div class='bloc'><p class='model'>"+heading+"</p></div>");
 return false;
 });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toNumDuplicate"> 
<input type="text" class="heading" />  
 
 <br/>  
 <br/>

  
 <input id="num-duplication" type="number" >

  
  <br/>
  <br/>
  
<button id="btn_dupliquate"> dupliquate </button>
</div>


 <div id="toDuplicate">
  <div class="common_preview" >
   <div class="bloc">
     <p class="model">test</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="result"></div>


<button id="btn_clone">clone</button>
```

Comment: What's the problem and/or question?

Comment: so what did you want your `clone` button to do? Just remove all the divs?

Comment: exactly what you want can you show some output?

Comment: I want to clone the whole part that is above the clone button and that the code is still functional (that is to say to be able to change the input text (class = "heading") and to be able to choose the quantity to be duplicated

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract your function to take dynamic selector strings for the duplicate button, duplicate number input, preview div and result div.

Comment: sorry I did not understand